# Is MySql Version 5.1 ready for production use?

Tags: mysql

We are currently using Mysql version 5.0 in our application and are thinking of moving to version 5.1
How stable is version 5.1.30 ?

EDIT

When version 5.0 was released it took a long time to become stable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL 5.1 recently went to [GA](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html), so apparently the dev team thought it was ready. I read a [lot](http://mysql-qa.blogspot.com/2008/12/mysql-51-ga-is-of-good-quality.html) [of](http://infosecurity.us/?p=3985) [contrasting](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/12/10/mysql-51-went-to-ga-was-it-a-good-move/) [views](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2008/12/20/today-i-recommended-mysql-51/) [on](http://blog.internetnews.com/skerner/2008/12/mysql-51-goes-ga-monty-not-hap.html) the quality of this release - the overall sentiment is that it's better than 5.0 was at the time, but you better check that you are not affected by some edge-cases which have not been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There was unfortunately some FUD surrounding the MySQL 5.1 GA release, decrying the less-than-perfect quality process and list of open bugs.  Once the dust settled, the general opinion was yes, it was less than perfect, but still better than MySQL 5.0.

Even if everyone lauded it as perfect, you should still test your application thoroughly before deploying any upgrade.  Your application's usage of MySQL may encounter none of its known open bugs, yet it may encounter bugs that are as yet unknown.

Comment: You'd call Monty's opinion FUD? http://monty-says.blogspot.com/2008/11/oops-we-did-it-again-mysql-51-released.html

Comment: I read Monty's blog the day it was posted, and yes I'd call that FUD.  Even more so because it comes from such a senior developer/founder of MySQL, and his words carry so much weight.

Comment: Then I guess your definition of FUD is a bit off. FUD, to be FUD, requires disinformation, not facts. He even says, very close to the beginning, "If you are using MySQL 5.1 just as a 'better' version of MySQL 5.0 and you don't plan to use any of the new features in MySQL 5.1 then you are ...

Comment: ... probably fine to try out MySQL 5.1. You should however not put it into production without testing it fully, preferably by running it on a couple of slaves for some weeks."

Comment: Monty's blog, while factually true, certainly engendered fear, uncertainty, and doubt in the user community.  I don't think FUD must necessarily contain falsehoods to have that effect.

Comment: The Wikipedia definition, to which I also subscribe, says otherwise. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt

By the way, disregarding the FUD bit (maybe replacing 'FUD' for 'problems'), I agree with what you've said :-).

Answer (score 0):

There are previous versions of MySQL that were far less ready, but were used quite successfully by major and minor sites. However, the expectation bar for MySQL is being raised, now that its provenance is evolving.

I've always found it critical to keep three things in mind with MySQL.

1. Stick to the mainstream best practices for the previous version. Existing features very seldom regress.
2. Test thoroughly (which is true for any product) - you never know for sure if your understanding of a feature matches the vendor's implementation.
3. Approach MySQL on its own terms; don't compare it with other RDBMS products. Its view of the responsibilities of the product and the responsibilities of the developer aren't aligned in the same way they are for RDBMS products from other major commercial vendors.